# FIFO to grep to file

Tags: linux, shell, redhat, fifo, rhel5

I am using a named pipe to trap syslog messages. I can then easily view syslog by doing something like

```
cat /var/log/local3.pipe | grep somefilter
or
grep somefilter /var/log/local3.pipe
```

These both output the syslogs to the console very nicely. However, if I then want to capture that to a file I get nothing, eg

```
cat /var/log/local3.pipe | grep somefilter >> somefile.log
or
grep somefilter /var/log/local3.pipe >> somefile.log
```

The file always remains as zero bytes. Does anyone know why? I'm using Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5. Thanks.

Additional info: For anyone who wants to reproduce this here's the full list of commands

```
su
<enter root password>
mkfifo /var/log/local3.pipe
chmod 644 /var/log/local3.pipe
echo "local3.* |/var/log/local3.pipe" >> /etc/syslog.conf
/etc/init.d/syslog restart
exit
```

then with one ssh session:

```
cat /var/log/local3.pipe
```

and in a second ssh session ("Test it" should show in first ssh session

```
logger -p local3.info "Test it"
```

then in the first session change it to

```
cat /var/log/local3.pipe >> somefile.log
```

send some more logs to local 3 (message needs to be different). Confirm that messages are going into somefile.log

```
logger -p local3.info "Test it 2"
```

then in the first session change it to

```
cat /var/log/local3.pipe | grep -i test >> somefile.log
```

now confirm that logs are not going to somefile.log

Note that the message needs to be different from the last message otherwise the logger doesn't send it immediately.

Comment: Are you first doing `grep somefilter /var/log/local3.pipe` and only then `grep somefilter /var/log/local3.pipe >>somefile.log`? Because the contents of the pipe will have been consumed by then.

Comment: Hi Cairnarvon. Before executing the second command I always terminate the first. I can switch back and forward between these 2 commands and the first always works and the second always results in a zero byte file. If I do cat /var/log/local3.pipe >> somefile.log then that works. It appears that putting grep into the mix (and piping to a file) stops things working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can reproduce your problem, and this fixes it for me:

```
cat /var/log/local3.pipe | grep -i --line-buffered test >> somefile.log
```

I think the reason is that when standard output refers to a terminal (according to `isatty(3)`), then line buffering is used, but as soon as you redirect to a file, libc switches to normal fixed-size buffering.  So you must have examined `somefile.log` before the `grep` process's standard output buffer was filled, therefore before it had any reason to write to the file.

Another way of forcing line-buffering is as follows:

```
cat /var/log/local3.pipe | stdbuf -oL grep -i test >> somefile.log
```

You can read more about all of this at these two great articles:

- http://www.perkin.org.uk/posts/how-to-fix-stdio-buffering.html
- http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/

(I'm amused to notice that `stdbuf` was written by a guy who emailed me today about something completely different - small world!)